# running filebeat on docker in ubuntu

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, filebeat

```
  sudo docker run docker.elastic.co/beats/filebeat:7.0.0 setup -E setup.kibana.host=localhost:5601 -E output.elasticsearch.hosts=["localhost:9200"]
```

I want to run filebeat on docker with elasticsearch but I get this error:

```
Exiting: Couldn't connect to any of the configured Elasticsearch hosts. Errors: [Error connection to Elasticsearch http://localhost:9200: Get http://localhost:9200: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:9200: connect: connection refused]
```

I didn't find any useful solution for  it ...

Answer (score 1):

From a container point-of-view, `localhost` is itself not the host machine where is running, that is why it can't connect to elasticsearch.

You would need to run the filebeat container on the host network or create a user-defined network for it and connect both filebeat and elasticsearch to that network.

Example:

```
$ sudo docker network create mynetwork --driver bridge
$ sudo docker run -d -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 --net=mynetwork --name elasticsearch -e "discovery.type=single-node" docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.0.0
$ sudo docker run -d --name kibana --net=mynetwork -p 5601:5601 kibana:7.0.0
$ sudo docker run --net=mynetwork --name filebeat docker.elastic.co/beats/filebeat:7.0.0 setup -E setup.kibana.host=kibana:5601 -E output.elasticsearch.hosts=["elasticsearch:9200"]
```